# aquery ajax callback 'method not allowed'

Tags: android, ajax, android-asynctask, aquery

I just tried to do AsyncTask with aquery. I have been successfully using AsyncTask aquery on some features in my application. But when I try to display data on listfragment error appears. Error that arises is 'method not allowed'

This is my script:

```
   public void callApiMomentApi(String email) {
    URL = Constant.URLApi.MOMENT;
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("email", email);
    resultListener.onApiPreCall();
    aq.ajaxCancel();

    try {
        aq.ajax(URL, params, String.class, callback);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        resultListener.onApiResultError(e.getMessage());
        Log.e("Moment","Aquery Error");
    }
}

private AjaxCallback<String> callback = new AjaxCallback<String>() {
    public void callback(String url, String result, AjaxStatus status) {
        if (result != null) {
            ApiDao apiDao = null;
            try {
                apiDao = gson.fromJson((result).toString(), ApiDao.class);

                if (apiDao.getSuccess().equals("true")) {
                    resultListener.onApiResultOk(apiDao.getData().get(0).getMoment());
                }
                else {
                    resultListener.onApiResultError(apiDao.getMessage());
                    Log.e("Moment","Tidak success");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                resultListener.onApiResultError(e.getMessage());
                Log.e("Moment","Exception e");
            }
        } else {
            resultListener.onApiResultError(status.getMessage());
            Log.e("Moment","Result Null");
        }
    };
};
```

Help me please, 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly your URL isn't the good one and the server is sending back a **405 Method Not Allowed**.

At least your server doesn't know how to handle it.
I don't think the problem is in your Android code.

Check your servlets and your URL.

Comment: The problem is the url , Thank you for your answer.